StrEnums and type narrowing (mypy)
I am fighting with type narrowing of StrEnums
To summarize my issue I have some abstract base class
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from enum import StrEnum

class Animal(ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def speak(animal_type: StrEnum):
        ...

and derivative classes each with their own StrEnums:
class FrogType(StrEnum):
    frog = "frog"
    toad = "toad"

class Frog(Animal):
    @staticmethod
    def speak(animal_type: FrogType):
        print(f"{animal_type} goes ribbit")

The following code works as expected:

Frog.speak(FrogType.frog)  # "frog goes ribbit"

and enums seem to be compatible:
print(isinstance(FrogType.frog, FrogType))  # True
print(isinstance(FrogType.frog, StrEnum))  # True

However MyPy doesnt recognize this as valid:
# python3.11 -m mypy frog.py
frog.py:16: error: Argument 1 of "speak" is incompatible with supertype "Animal"; supertype defines the argument type as "StrEnum"  [override]
frog.py:16: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
frog.py:16: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

This seems to be a valid type narrowing, so I must be annoting something wrong. What would be a correct solution?

You can avoid this issue by using a generic in place of StrEnum. Below AnimalType is defined such that it has a bound of StrEnum:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from enum import StrEnum
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

AnimalType = TypeVar("AnimalType", bound=StrEnum)
class Animal(ABC, Generic[AnimalType]):
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def speak(animal_type: AnimalType):
        ...

class FrogType(StrEnum):
    frog = "frog"
    toad = "toad"

class Frog(Animal[FrogType]):
    @staticmethod
    def speak(animal_type: FrogType):
        print(f"{animal_type} goes ribbit")

print(isinstance(FrogType.frog, FrogType))  # True
print(isinstance(FrogType.frog, StrEnum))  # True

Hope this helps!

@Mark's answer already explained the how; this answer explains the why.
Animal's .speak() accepts all instances of StrEnum, but Frog's .speak() only accepts instances of FrogType, a subset of that. This violates Liskov's substitution principle in that an instance of Frog cannot replace an instance of Animal:
class Fish(Animal): pass

class FishType(StrEnum):
  shark = auto()

a: Animal = get_fish_or_frog()

# If a is an Animal or a Fish,
# this is fine, because Animal.speak() accepts any kind of StrEnum.
a.speak(FishType.shark)

# However, if `a` is a Frog, that wouldn't be fine
# because Frog.speak() accepts only FrogType.

Or, from the link Mypy gave:
class A:
    def test(self, t: Sequence[int]) -> Sequence[str]:
        ...

class GeneralizedArgument(A):
    # A more general argument type is okay
    def test(self, t: Iterable[int]) -> Sequence[str]:  # OK
        ...

class NarrowerArgument(A):
    # A more specific argument type isn't accepted
    def test(self, t: List[int]) -> Sequence[str]:  # Error
        ...

Note that this is not "type narrowing". Type narrowing is when you use some flow structure to narrow the possible types of an object:
a: int | str

if isinstance(a, int):
  # Here a is an int
  ...

